# Open 2 Webdrivers at same time with multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am working on Crawl project using `Selenium` and `Webdriver`. Since that data I need to crawl while big, I want to split it to 2 `threads` and run at the same time. But when I start 2 `Webdrivers` at the same time, my code can not recognize which `driver` belong to which `thread` to fill the information.

1. This is the code that I setup 2 `threads` run `main` function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data(INPUT_DIR)

    t1_data = data[:250]
    t2_data = data[250:]

    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(main, (t1_data, LOG_FILE_T1))
        _thread.start_new_thread(main, (t2_data, LOG_FILE_T2))
    except:
        print ("Error: unable to start thread")

    while 1:
        pass
```

2. This code I start the `Webdriver`:

```
def start_driver():

    global driver

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notification")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    #options.add_argument("headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

3. Two `Webdrivers` after started, I will fill in the username/password
   information on facebook.com

```
def login(email, password):
    """ Logging into our own profile """

    try:
        driver.get('https://mbasic.facebook.com')
        time.sleep(DELAY_TIME)

        driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element_by_name('pass').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()

        # deal with "Not Now" button if it show off at first time
        not_now_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a")
        if not_now_button.size != 0:
            not_now_button.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in Login')
        print(e)
        exit()
```

At `send_keys` step, both `threads` fill in the same text box in 1 `Webdriver`.
How can I change my code for 2 `threads` can see different `Webdrive` and fill the info in ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the solution, I want to share here if someone needed.

Instead of `global driver`, I will change to a local `driver` and pass it to each `function`.

```
def start_driver():

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notification")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    #options.add_argument("headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver
```

```
def login(driver, email, password):
    """ Logging into our own profile """

    try:
        driver.get('https://mbasic.facebook.com')
        time.sleep(DELAY_TIME)

        driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element_by_name('pass').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()

        # deal with "Not Now" button if it show off at first time
        not_now_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a")
        if not_now_button.size != 0:
            not_now_button.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in Login')
        print(e)
        exit()
```

By this, 2 `threads` can see different `Webdriver` and fill their own information.